# How to disable ElasticSearch using terminal?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I was using ElasticSearch in my old server and then I migrate the server for a new one that it's not using it anymore, so I'm receiving this issue message below.

[image: ElasticSearch issue]

```
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

I could I change the search engine to the default using terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**⚠️ Since Magento 2.4, ElasticSearch is required and MySQL is not supported as a search engine anymore.**

You can use the Magento 2 CLI to do it, you can check your current **search engine** using:

```
php -f bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine
```

[image: magerun2 to get the catalog search engine]

After that you can set to the default one using the `config:set` feature, like that:

```
php -f bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'mysql'
```

Or you can run this SQL query in your DB:

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'catalog/search/engine'
```

Comment: its worked but show another error:  "Your current search engine, 'MySQL', is not supported. You must install a supported search engine before upgrading. See the System Upgrade Guide for more information"

Comment: @matinict If you're using Magento 2.4, ElasticSearch is required and MySQL is not supported as a search engine anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this module to disable elasticsearch engine:
https://github.com/zepgram/module-disable-search-engine

Answer (score 0):

Magento CLI is also able to handle that:

```
magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'mysql'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for Magento 2.4.x as Elasticsearch is mandatory on that version: https://github.com/zepgram/module-disable-search-engine

```
composer require zepgram/module-disable-search-engine
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```